# How to add springboot application monitoring to prometheus in Kubernetes?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, helm3

Good afternoon everyone, I have a question about adding monitoring of the application itself to prometheus.
I am using spring boot actuator and see the values for prometheus accordingly: https://example.com/actuator/prometheus
I have raised prometheus via the default helm chart ( `helm -n monitor upgrade -f values.yaml pg prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` )by adding default values for it:

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  job_name: prometheus
  scrape_interval: 40s
  scrape_timeout: 40s
  metrics_path: /actuator/prometheus
  scheme: https
```

Prometheus itself can be found at http://ex.com/prometheus
The deployment.yaml file of my springboot application is as follows:

```
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/path: /actuator/prometheus
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "8080"
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
          value: {{ .Values.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
        - name: DATASOURCE_USERNAME
          value: {{ .Values.DATASOURCE_USERNAME }}
        - name: DATASOURCE_URL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://database-postgresql:5432/dev-school
        name : {{ .Release.Name }}
        image: {{ .Values.container.image }}
        ports:
        - containerPort : 8080
```

However, after that prometheus still can't see my values.
Can you tell me what the error could be?

Comment: Check in Prometheus UI console if you can see targets (instances of your application). If so, there might be an error message. If you can't find any targets related to your app, it seems the problem is in service discovery.

Comment: @anemyte yes, I can't find any targets. Should I create a ServiceMonitor?

Comment: Dunno, sorry. I never used the operator, always connecting all the pieces with my own configuration files. That was just a general advice which works either way. Check the operator docs to learn how it finds targets or look for a question on this site. I'm sure this has been asked before.

Comment: Try adding `-` symbol before `job_name` in `additionalScrapeConfigs`. `additionalScrapeConfigs` is a list of dictionaries, and each job should be it's own dict.

Answer (score 3):

In prometheus-operator,

`additionalScrapeConfigs` is not used in this way.

According to documentation [Additional Scrape Configuration](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/additional-scrape-config.md):
**AdditionalScrapeConfigs** allows specifying a key of a Secret containing additional Prometheus scrape configurations.

The easiest way to add new scrape config is to use a `servicemonitor`, like the example below:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: example-app
  labels:
    team: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  endpoints:
  - port: web
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I try to use it.